# Selenium - не могу указать на кнопку

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Нужно написать код, который будет вбивать в поиск запрос, нажимать кнопку "Найти", затем переходить по ссылке, всплывающей в середине экрана в таблице

[image: Нужно нажать на красное]

Вот сайт
https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration

Мой код уже делает первые два шага, но с кликанием по красной области проблемы

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get('https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration')

content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[_ngcontent-c27]')
content.send_keys('ЕАЭС N RU Д-TR.РА01.А.44855/19')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Найти")]').click()
```

Не знаю, как задать эту область. Вот код области

```html
<td class="htDimmed" style="height: 38px;">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-checkbox-cell _nghost-c42="">
      <p-checkbox _ngcontent-c42="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
          <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input type="checkbox" name="undefined" value="undefined"></div>
          <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable"></span></div>
        </div>
        <!---->
      </p-checkbox>
    </fgis-h-table-checkbox-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-image-cell _nghost-c43="">
      <!----><img _ngcontent-c43="" src="assets/images/statuses/published.png" alt="Действует" title="Действует" class="ng-star-inserted"></fgis-h-table-image-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">ЕАЭС N RU Д-TR.РА01.А.44855/19</div>
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip-triangle"></div>
        <fgis-tooltip _ngcontent-c44="" _nghost-c9=""></fgis-tooltip>
      </div>
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">14.05.2019</div>
      <!---->
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">14.05.2044</div>
      <!---->
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "КОМПЛЕКТСТРОЙ"</div>
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip-triangle"></div>
        <fgis-tooltip _ngcontent-c44="" _nghost-c9=""></fgis-tooltip>
      </div>
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">H.K.S. HAS ASANSOR KAUCUK, PLASTIK, METAL SAN.ve TIC. LTD. STI</div>
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip-triangle"></div>
        <fgis-tooltip _ngcontent-c44="" _nghost-c9=""></fgis-tooltip>
      </div>
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">Лифт</div>
      <!---->
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="htDimmed">
  <a data-href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" href="/rds/declaration/view/12568570" class="h-table-cell-link-wrapper">
    <fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell _nghost-c44="">
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__text">Испытания проводились в аккредитованной в ЕАЭС лаборатории</div>
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c44="" class="limited-text-cell__tooltip-triangle"></div>
        <fgis-tooltip _ngcontent-c44="" _nghost-c9=""></fgis-tooltip>
      </div>
    </fgis-h-table-limited-text-cell>
  </a>
</td>
```

Помогите с методами или тэгами, пожалуйста.

Comment: `driver.implicitly_wait(3)` достаточно один раз указать :)

Answer (score 0):

Все нашлось через

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[2]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Хотя не очень понятно, как работает последняя фунция.

Comment: В `ActionChains` вы указывайте команды (move_to_element и click), а при `perform` они выполняются